# How to create a logic function in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, sorting

I have a column in Excel which looks like this:

```
A1 cell:  gi|948971612|gb|JQBK01000038.1|
A2 cell:  gi|948958729|gb|JQBK01000277.1|
A3 cell:  gi|948968182|gb|JQBK01000119.1|
```

Now in B column there is a really big text which looks like this:

```
    >gi|948971612|gb|JQBK01000038.1| Lactobacillus acidipiscis strain DSM 15353 Scaffold295, whole genome shotgun sequence
CAACCATTCCATCTGCAATGATCAACTGGACTTGTTCTAATCCACGTTTTTTAAGATCTTCTGCCATTTC
TGACCAAACTCCTGCATTTTCACTTGGAGCGATTCGATAATCAAGAACTTCTTTGATGCCGACAGATGTA
ATACCTAAAGCAATATAGACCGCTTCTCTTTGAACTGAATCGCGGCGCAAAGGTAAGTAAGTTG   
    >gi|948957817|gb|JQBK01000039.1| Lactobacillus acidipiscis strain DSM 15353 Scaffold296, whole genome shotgun sequence
    ATCGGTCGAGGACTTAACCAACGAGTCGCGTGTGTGGGCTCGGTCAGATAAAAGCAGCAAGAAATGAATG
    TTAGTCAGTTTTGAGGGAATGGATCTCTCAAAGAAAAAAACACAAGTGCGGTGGCGATAGCACGAAGGCT
    ACACATGTTCCCATGCCGAACACAGCAGTTAAGCTTCGTCACGCCAAGAGTAGTTGGGGGAT
    >gi|948957803|gb|JQBK01000040.1| Lactobacillus acidipiscis strain DSM 15353 Scaffold297, whole genome shotgun sequence
    AAGCAAGGAGCTCAAGGAGCAAGTAAACAACTTTCACATTTAGGAAAGGGACTAATGGGCGTAATGGGCT
    CAATTATCCAGTCCGCCTATCAGATTCAACAACAAAACCGCTATATTGCAAAACGAAACGCCTATTATGC
    TCAACAGCAACAGCGCAGAAACCACCGCAGACAACAGGAAGATGAAATTGAACGTTAACGA
```

I'd like to use a function to a new column that will be able to find the content for each A column cell `(for example for A1 cell is: "gi|948971612|gb|JQBK01000038.1|")` where is located in this B column big messy text and when it finds this content, then to copy the text from `">gi|948971612|gb|JQBK01000038.1|"` till the next`">gi"` that starts. I mean the final result to copy in the new cell in this example is this:

```
">gi|948971612|gb|JQBK01000038.1| Lactobacillus acidipiscis strain DSM 15353 Scaffold295, whole genome shotgun sequence
CAACCATTCCATCTGCAATGATCAACTGGACTTGTTCTAATCCACGTTTTTTAAGATCTTCTGCCATTTC
TGACCAAACTCCTGCATTTTCACTTGGAGCGATTCGATAATCAAGAACTTCTTTGATGCCGACAGATGTA
ATACCTAAAGCAATATAGACCGCTTCTCTTTGAACTGAATCGCGGCGCAAAGGTAAGTAAGTTG"
```

If it isn't able to be done with Excel, any other suggestions are more that welcomed!

Comment: May we see what you have tried, even if it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have excel with 2 columns: A, B

And you want put some searched sub string of B into C, which meets the condition related with column A described in your question?

You can build VBA macro to do that easily if you know some VB language,
Or simply you can put following formula in column C.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(">"&A1, B1)),MID(B1,SEARCH(">"&A1, B1),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(">", B1,SEARCH(">"&A1, B1)+1)),SEARCH(">", B1,SEARCH(">"&A1, B1)+1)-SEARCH(">"&A1, B1),LEN(B1)-SEARCH(">"&A1, B1))),"")
```

So this formula finds A from B, and if not found, just simply put empty string,
but if found, then cut the string from the found position to the first occurrence of ">".
Hope this formula solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Yes that's exactly my question. I tried to run your formula but it always returns to me syntax errors. Even if i try to run "=FIND(A1,B1)" it returns me a syntax error. Have you any idea what is going on? Thanks again for your help, it's really appreciated!

Comment: Well, do following, copy my formula, double click your cell, so that it will be in edit mod, and then paste my formula, and then press Enter key. It must be working as I tested my self already. Please do not forget to accept my answer if it works okay. :D

Comment: Please check the xls file here. it has the example. Column C has the formula. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwj2ggMirXYaUkZ0ZVpZVGlZZmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Ray! It really seems to work with your example, i'm amazed! I tried with my document but again i have to result. I think something is going wrong with this big text of B column because it can't be pasted only in B1 cell and it takes an area from B1 to B33563 when pasted. I tried by changing your "B1" fields with "B:B:" to search in all B column but nothing..  Can you please try with my original document if you can find a way that works? https://www.dropbox.com/s/9y7f3xmixjksqn6/15353%20versus%20chromosome.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: @Sakis your text is too long for excel cell. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#bmcalculation  According to them, Total number of characters that a cell can contain is 32,767 characters. You d better use VBA programming tech to solve the issue.

Comment: Yes i understand about characters limitation for every cell. But when i copy the big text in B column, excel splits this in thousand cells. So if i could change B1 with something like B:B or B1:B35000 and function searches all B column and not only in B1 cell, your function should work like harm. I don't understand the reason why the function can not search all B column If i change the B1 parameter.. Do you know why this happens? I have no words to say to you for helping me with this issue, but THANK you so much Ray!

Comment: First of all, if you wanna say thank to me, you can do that by marking my answer as accepted. Second, in order to make my function working, you need to replace B1 with CONCATENATE(B:B). But the problem is, because your B text is too large, Excel can not handle that in workbook. I guess you d better choose other options...

Comment: Thanks Ray for all your help! I just said "Thank you", you really helped a lot! I'll do my best to create a Macro as you suggested! All best!

Comment: @Sakis it s my please and glad to hear that my answer was helpful. So, yeah, using Macro will be better idea, as it does not have short limit of memory, so you concat the column B 's cell values into one variable, and then apply the logic - find, and cut the needed text. And thanks for accepting my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "big text" is in B1,

```
in C1 enter: =FIND(A1,B1)    
in D1 enter: =FIND(">gi", B1, C1)  
in E1 enter: =MID(A1, C1, D1-C1)
```

E1 contains the text you want.